# Anchor tag(s) in jsTree node generating error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jstree

I tried adding anchor tags within the li tag, but it generates the following error, which has been driving me crazy. I'm assuming it's because jsTree is automatically adding an anchor tag just under the li tag, and therefore, I am placing an anchor within an anchor.

> angular.js:13920TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of
>   undefined

Here is the markup:

```
<div id="jstree_dbs_div">
     <ul>
         {% for type in types %}
             <li data-jstree='{"checkbox_disabled":true}'>
                 {{ type['parent']['text'] }} <span><a href="#">edit</a></span>
             </li>
         {% endfor %}
     </ul>
</div>
```

If I remove that anchor tag, it works fine (ie. no error).

Here is the jsTree config:

```
$jsTree.jstree({
    "core": {
        multiple: false,
    },
    "conditionalselect": function (node, event) {
        return false;
    },
    "plugins" : [ "wholerow", "checkbox", "conditionalselect" ],
    "checkbox": { cascade: "", three_state: false },
}).on("ready.jstree", function() {
    $jsTree.jstree('open_all');
}).on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var href = data.node.a_attr.href;
    document.location.href = href;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping my jsTree config in a timeout seems to have fixed the error. I also added a few other things (which had nothing to do with the original problem).

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $jsTree = $('#jstree_dbs_div');

    $jsTree.jstree({
        "core": {
            multiple: false,
        },
        "conditionalselect": function (node, event) {
            var href = event.target.href;
            document.location.href = href;

            return false;
        },
        "plugins" : [ "wholerow", "checkbox", "conditionalselect" ],
        "checkbox": { cascade: "", three_state: false },
    }).on("ready.jstree", function() {
        $jsTree.jstree('open_all');
    });
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see issues with adding this functionality, as far as you can control markup inside the jsTree node. Even if jsTree doesn't let you get an embedded link, you can still reach it with regular javascript as below, also check demo - [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/j76evppr/). However, it is not Angular.

In a tree node config:

```
{ "id": ..., 
  "parent": ..., 
  "text": "Text before link<a class='link' href='www.google.com'>google.com</a>" 
}
```

and then in the event handler:

```
.on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var href = $(data.event.currentTarget).find('.link').attr('href');
    document.location.href = href;
});
```

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example where you build the tree with markup (like in my example), rather than JSON, and then render it?

Comment: It won't work, so just use spans styled as links - https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/abq5b274/

Comment: Originally I had my anchors wrapped inside a span, in the node. That worked to display it nicely, but still generated that error. Check the answer I posted, which fixed it. Kind of a hack, but it works.

Comment: Cool, glad for you!